# Unify variable if the condition is met

Tags: prolog

I want to assign a value to a variable `R`, but the value depends on the condition.

```
if (cond1)
  var = value1 + 5;
else if (cond2)
  var = value1 + 10;
else
  var = value2 + value3 + value4;
```

This is how I tried, but if the first condition fails, var is assigned a value which makes the bounding afterwards fail.

```
[...], (cond1 -> Var is value1 + 5; 
        cond2 -> Var is value1 + 10;
        Var is value2 + value3 + value4
       ), [...]
```

Comment: What do conds look like? Give some examples! btw. `var` should better be `Var`, same for `value`.

Comment: It would be better of you showed the actual code that you have, it is much easier than trying to guess what you really have.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *`Var` is assigned a value which makes the bounding afterwards fail*. Your Prolog "if-then-else" type of construct looks like it should reflect your C-ish example. Certainly if `Var` is bound by the if-then-else, then it cannot subsequently be rebound to a different value within the same predicate clause. That's just how Prolog works.

Comment: When cond1 fails, R is assigned 100 for some reason. When I get to the else, I get 100 is 40 + ..., which fails

Comment: What is `R`? There's no `R` in your code. Perhaps you should show your actual code in question, especially what you actually have for `[...]`, `cond1`, and `cond2`, etc. In the example you have written, I am assuming by `R` you're referring to `Var`, whose value may have been set by the prior `[...]` but it's unclear. The operator `;` is lower precedence than `->` or `is/2`, so the conditional as you have it written should do what you expect (looking at it in isolation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an error on my side: R was already unified before the conditions (in the [...] part), which resulted in something like this:

`100 is 40 + 39 + 20 <--- FAIL`

Changing the name of the variable solved it.

Comment: Right! Using too few variable names and resulting unexpected behavior (faillure / exception) *can* be a showstopper.

Answer (score 1):

There are no assignments in Prolog, just unifications. The following may work:

You unify `R` with the second argument of a rule `foo`

```
foo(Value, R)
```

The rule `foo` may be constructed as follows:

```
foo(Value, X) :- cond1, !, X is Value + 5.
foo(Value, X) :- cond2, !, X is Value + 10.
foo(Value, X) :- X is whatever.
```

Comment: @Jonathan This is exactly the same as the code in your question. There is no reason to prefer this to your original attempt. It is more likely that you have some kind of typo or think-o in your actual code (which you have not shown).

Comment: I posted the error as an answer, should I delete the question or simply accept my answer and move on?